# My permutation code prints nPn every time?

Tags: string, algorithm, recursion, double, permutation

So I am trying to write a code that will print out all of the permutations of a string following the nPr way where n is the string length and r is an input. It takes in a prefix and the String, and an integer. It does this except it prints nPn permutations every time instead of nPr permutation.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String x = "abcd";
    permu("", x, 2);
}
public static void permu(String pre, String x, int r){
    if(x.length() == 0)
        System.out.println(pre.substring(0, r));
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
            permu(pre + x.charAt(i), x.substring(0, i) + x.substring(i + 1, x.length()), r);
    }
}
```

For r = 2, I want it to print ab, ac, ad, ba, bc, bd, ca, cb, cd, da, db, dc. but it prints double of everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set recursion limit to `r` (now it is `n`). Probably so:

```
   if(x.length() == 0)
 change to
   if(pre.length() == r)
```

Answer (score 0):

The result shouldn't surprise you: Your code determines all 24 permutations. It enforces the maximum length only when printing. You can tell that, because `r` isn't used anywhere except when printing.

If you print the whole string, the result is:

```
abcd
abdc
acbd
acdb
....
```

You see only the first characters of what is essentially a full permutation.

If you want to have a genuine pick of 2 out of 4, you should stop recursing after you have picked `r` items:

```
if (pre.length() == r)
    System.out.println(pre.substring(0, r));
```

You may want to make sure the code still works when someone calls it with an `r` that is larger than the string length:

```
if (pre.length() == r || x.length() == 0)
    System.out.println(pre.substring(0, r));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I thought that you mathematically can't do that, since r has to be less than or equal to n

Comment: That doesn't stop anyone from calling `permu("", "abcd", 12)`. The code is just a safeguard against bad input.